# to hide and unhide datagrid rows dynamically using vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have a datagrid which rows have dynamically generated Id's and I need to hide its alternate rows on Pageload.Rows which are shown on pageload have an image which click event will unhide the row.

for this I have called HideTable function on body onload event.

```
function hideTable()

 dim rown

 for rown = 1 to 21     
 document.getElementById("DatagridM_Dtlgrd1" & rown).style.display = "none"
 document.getElementById("DGMRPFC170_Dtlgrd2" & rown).style.display = "none"

 rown = rown + 1
 next

end function
```

and On Imageclick function to unhide row I have done this

```
function ImgClick(ByVal RowNum , ByVal ImgStatus)

 dim rows

 rows = RowNum - 1

 document.getElementById("DatagridM_Dtlgrd1" & rows).style.display = "block"
 document.getElementById("DGMRPFC170_Dtlgrd2" & rows).style.display = "block"

end function
```

Now everything going good but when I click on Image this will again go Hidetable () and give a javascript error that "document.getElementById is undefined".

how to achive it.Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: @Dashisht Bhardwaj is right although his contribution does not provide an answer to the question: _Please post the code where you are using these functions_, i.e. a part where the `ImgClick` function is called from. What is the `RowNum` argument value?

Comment: This is the row where imgclick is being used. an image is bind in rows of datagrid on click of which 1 row will be unhide like drilldown